# Hide everything but the Edit item button in Display Form SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007

I need a javascript code to hide everything but the Edit Item button in the display form, i tried with CSS but it hides the entire row of buttons.

Comment: USe CSS selectors to target everything you want

Answer (score 0):

For edit button use this in CSS

```
 visibility: visible !important;
```